# Ansible: referencing hosts.yml variables in group variables with YAML anchors

Tags: ansible, yaml

I've got a problem with anchors in Ansible [2.9]. I try to do this:

```
hosts.yml:
somegroup:
  somehost:
    ext_ip: &somehost_int_ip "10.20.30.40"

group_variables/somegroup.yml
firewall_inbound_ok:
- { src: << *somehost_int_ip, ports: ["1234"], rule "allow" }
```

Now, when I run a playbook the anchor gets ignored, like when I'd omit the `src:` key.

I've tried this syntax:

```
- { src: <<: *somehost_int_ip, ports: ["1234"], rule "allow" }
```

But all I get is a parse error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected ',' or '}'

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/.../group_vars/somegroup.yml': line 95, column 14, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

   - { src: <<: *somehost_ext_ip, proto: "tcp", ports: [ "27017" ], rule: "allow" }
             ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
[...]
```

The same error shows when I try referencing `somehost_int_ip` like this:

```
- { src: *somehost_int_ip, ports: ["1234"], rule "allow" }
```

It's quite possible I don't get the idea of YAML anchors, but then again it's a tricky situation here, different from the anchor tutorial Ansible provides.

Any ideas? My goal is to keep `somehost_int_ip` definition in one place and re-use it later when constructing a list of dictionaries (firwall rules), for obvious playbook clarity and management reasons.

Previously I've tried this approach:

```
- { src: hostvars['somehost']['ext_ip'], ports: ["1234"], rule "allow" }
```

but the error I get from Ansible is pretty similar:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected ',' or '}'
The offending line appears to be:

  - { src: hostvars['emie05']['ext_ip'], ports: ["1234"], rule "allow" }
                   ^ here
```

Me need help. 8^)

Comment: YAML anchors don't work across files, which is what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: OK, I get it. So is there any other way of re-using variables set in hosts in group variables file in the current Ansible release?

Comment: Ansible does *not* evaluate jinja2 expressions in `group_vars` files, but it *will* evaluate them when it touches the dict key, which can often make it appear like it does. Thus, in `group_variables/somegroup.yml` you can say `src: "{{ ext_ip }}"` and it will likely do what you want. The reason your previous attempt didn't work is that you tried to use the term `hostvars` as if it was in a jinja2 expression but it wasn't